# NodeJS - Pug - Add variable from database in input value

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, pug

I'm trying to show the value from `#{product.name}` in a textfield. This is my code, but it doesn't work

```
label Name
input(type='text', placeholder='Name', name='name' value='#{product.name}')
```

This is my result:

[image: Screenshot]

Can someone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming that you are using a newer version of pug, string interpolation in attributes [has been removed from the language in favor of ES6-template-strings](https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/2305).

This means you are in theory supposed to use syntax like this now:

```
input(type='text', placeholder='Name', name='name' value=`${product.name}`)
```

That being said, your example does not require using interpolation at all, and you could simply be passing the variable's value:

```
input(type='text', placeholder='Name', name='name', value=product.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

input(type="text", name="hidden", value=product.name, checked="")